# Debugging in Safari or Chrome

Tags: rest

I am trying to debug a rest call on a website. Is there a way I can know what web server a certain rest call is hitting using Developer tools from Safari or Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Open Chrome Developer tools > Networks tab and then make the rest call on the website. You'll see a new entry in the networks tab. If you just click on it and see the headers, you should see the URL of the webserver it is hitting.

Comment: @user9179677: Please accept it as an answer if this works for you.